# Mixed effect models where one fixed effect leads to very different outcomes

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model

I am running a pilot experiment that is testing whether a modified form of music notation results in fewer errors in performance than conventional music notation.

Our experiment involves participants playing two pieces of music at sight, one in version 1 (conventional) and one in version 2 (modified). They play both pieces twice, consecutively, giving two readings for each piece (reading 1, reading 2). As everyone plays two pieces there is also an effect of order (order 1 and order 2) that we want to test for — particularly as there might be an effect of going from one form of notation to the other.

The order of piece and which version they received of each was randomised using a Latin square design.

The resulting data takes the form of counts of errors for each performance.

When we run a model with version, order and reading as fixed effects, accounting for piece and participant_id as random effects:

```
total_errors_mdl <- glmer(formula = total_errors ~ version + order + reading + (1 | participant_id) + (1 | piece), data = total_errors_table, family = poisson)
```

It shows a highly significant reduction in errors in the second readings (as expected), a significant reduction in errors using the modified notation (as hoped!) and a smaller increase in errors in the second pieces played (interesting, and not expected).

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: total_errors ~ version + order + reading + (1 | participant_id) +      (1 | piece)
   Data: total_errors_table

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   848.8    866.1   -418.4    836.8      126 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.3973 -0.7909 -0.0879  0.7493  3.5087 

Random effects:
 Groups         Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 participant_id (Intercept) 0.5122   0.7157  
 piece          (Intercept) 0.0384   0.1960  
Number of obs: 132, groups:  participant_id, 33; piece, 6

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  2.24876    0.16183  13.896  < 2e-16 ***
version2    -0.17139    0.05644  -3.037  0.00239 ** 
order2       0.12503    0.05862   2.133  0.03295 *  
reading2    -0.43060    0.05511  -7.813 5.58e-15 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
         (Intr) versn2 order2
version2 -0.200              
order2   -0.213  0.212       
reading2 -0.134  0.000  0.000
```

But, we suspect that in addition to each participant being different, that the impact of the modified notation on different people might also vary, so we ran a model with the effect of version being allowed to vary for each participant:

```
total_errors_mdl <- glmer(formula = total_errors ~ version + order + reading + (version | participant_id) + (1 | piece), data = total_errors_table, family = poisson)
```

Which shows, interestingly, that version is no longer significant:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: total_errors ~ version + order + reading + (version | participant_id) +      (1 | piece)
   Data: total_errors_table

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   824.4    847.4   -404.2    808.4      124 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.3958 -0.6602 -0.0799  0.5380  3.1834 

Random effects:
 Groups         Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 participant_id (Intercept) 0.75472  0.8687        
                version2    0.28747  0.5362   -0.64
 piece          (Intercept) 0.03314  0.1820        
Number of obs: 132, groups:  participant_id, 33; piece, 6

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  2.16075    0.19186  11.262  < 2e-16 ***
version2    -0.06547    0.12141  -0.539    0.590    
order2       0.12694    0.11431   1.110    0.267    
reading2    -0.43060    0.05494  -7.838 4.58e-15 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
         (Intr) versn2 order2
version2 -0.566              
order2   -0.327  0.106       
reading2 -0.113  0.000  0.000
```

But digging into the data, it seems like the more errors a participant makes, the greater the effect of positive impact of version 2, and if we subset the participants into two groups, based on whether they made below or above the median error count for all four of their performances, we get what looks like a really interesting result:

A highly significant reduction in errors using version 2 for weaker performers:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: total_errors ~ version + order + reading + (version | participant_id) +      (1 | piece)
   Data: filtered_data

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   485.1    502.9   -234.6    469.1       60 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.4242 -0.6796 -0.1706  0.6079  3.0676 

Random effects:
 Groups         Name        Variance  Std.Dev.  Corr
 participant_id (Intercept) 1.979e-01 4.448e-01     
                version2    2.499e-01 4.999e-01 0.00
 piece          (Intercept) 6.126e-10 2.475e-05     
Number of obs: 68, groups:  participant_id, 17; piece, 6

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   2.8445     0.1554  18.307  < 2e-16 ***
version2     -0.4185     0.1534  -2.728  0.00638 ** 
order2        0.2120     0.1386   1.529  0.12618    
reading2     -0.3721     0.0618  -6.021 1.73e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
         (Intr) versn2 order2
version2 -0.321              
order2   -0.642  0.375       
reading2 -0.162  0.000  0.000
optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

But a significant increase in errors for stronger performers:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: total_errors ~ version + order + reading + (version | participant_id) +      (1 | piece)
   Data: filtered_data_low

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   304.1    321.3   -144.0    288.1       56 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.62754 -0.78030 -0.01563  0.53448  3.08984 

Random effects:
 Groups         Name        Variance Std.Dev.  Corr 
 participant_id (Intercept) 2.49e-01 4.990e-01      
                version2    1.56e-01 3.950e-01 -0.93
 piece          (Intercept) 3.00e-09 5.477e-05      
Number of obs: 64, groups:  participant_id, 16; piece, 6

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   1.6151     0.1726   9.356  < 2e-16 ***
version2      0.4445     0.1685   2.638  0.00833 ** 
order2       -0.2545     0.1438  -1.771  0.07664 .  
reading2     -0.6523     0.1224  -5.330  9.8e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
         (Intr) versn2 order2
version2 -0.692              
order2   -0.262 -0.237       
reading2 -0.243  0.000  0.000
optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

Bearing all of this in mind…! Is there a way to reveal this finding from one overall model, without needing to subset the data into two groups of participants in this way? (I'm also unsure of the significance of the "boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')" errors when running the models on the subsetted data.

And leading on from that, is there a similar approach that can reveal the differing effects of interactions between version, reading and order on different participants. Particularly — when going from modified first (version 2, order 1) to conventional (version 1, order 2) there is a large increase in errors for weaker performers, but a decrease in errors for the better performers — which the overall model doesn't represent.

The head of the dataset is given below — any help would be much appreciated, as these kinds of model are very new to me! Thank you.

```
structure(list(expt = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), participant_id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 6L, 6L), levels = c("1_1", "1_10", "1_11", "1_14", "1_15", 
"1_2", "1_5", "1_6", "1_7", "1_9", "2_1", "2_10", "2_11", "2_12", 
"2_13", "2_14", "2_15", "2_17", "2_18", "2_2", "2_20", "2_21", 
"2_22", "2_23", "2_24", "2_25", "2_3", "2_4", "2_5", "2_6", "2_7", 
"2_8", "2_9"), class = "factor"), grade = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("5", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), 
    piece = structure(c(5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L), levels = c("5_1", 
    "5_6", "6_1", "6_3", "7_1", "7_5"), class = "factor"), order = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    version = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("1", 
    "2"), class = "factor"), reading = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), tempo = c(88, 
    88, 88, 88, 95, 95), total_errors = c(8, 8, 26, 23, 7, 6), 
    sum_pitch_errors = c(6, 3, 18, 14, 5, 4), sum_rhythm_errors = c(2, 
    4, 7, 7, 2, 2), sum_metre_errors = c(0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0), sum_time_errors = c(2, 
    5, 8, 9, 2, 2), error_bars_per_piece = c(6, 4, 8, 5, 5, 4
    ), error_free_bars_per_piece = c(16, 18, 8, 11, 17, 18), 
    percentage_error_free_bars = c(72.7272727272727, 81.8181818181818, 
    50, 68.75, 77.2727272727273, 81.8181818181818), error_level = c("below_median", 
    "below_median", "below_median", "below_median", "below_median", 
    "below_median")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to reveal this finding from one overall model,

To subset the data, you have probably created a binary indicator for weaker and stronger performers. You could use this variable as a predictor in your overall model, and include possible interactions of this variable with the predictors already in your model.

> I'm also unsure of the significance of the "boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')" errors when running the models on the subsetted data.

Inspect the `Random effects:` output, (some of) the random effects have variances very close to zero. Variances cannot go below 0, causing the `boundary` warning. Random effects with close to zero variance can often be omitted, including them only as fixed effects assumes their variance is 0.

Note that the following sounds like p-hacking a lot:

> But digging into the data, it seems like the more errors a participant makes, the greater the effect of positive impact of version 2, and if we subset the participants into two groups, based on whether they made below or above the median error count for all four of their performances, we get what looks like a really interesting result:

After digging into the data to find hypotheses, and testing these hypotheses with the very same data, the standard errors and p-values of your hypothesis tests are not valid anymore, so these should be taken with many grains of salt. It is perhaps better to focus on the strength of the effects, e.g., by computing an effect size. And on replicating the effect in a new experiment or dataset, not used for generating the hypotheses to be tested.